# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo for wallpaper app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception

I was trying to do a wallpaper application.I am all done but every time i open the app its crashes.

This is my Activity

```
package com.wallpaper.rahuldravid;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
        Integer [] pics= {
            R.drawable.sunset,
            R.drawable.winter

};
ImageView imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Gallery ga = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


ga.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int pos,long id) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You have selected picture " + (pos+1) +"of Rd", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        imageView.setImageResource(pics[pos]);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(v.getContext());
            try {
                wm.setResource(pics[pos]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        });
    }
});

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context ctx;
int imageBackground;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        ctx = c;
        TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
        ta.recycle();
    }


public int getCount() {

    return pics.length;
}


public Object getItem(int arg0) {

    return arg0;
}


public long getItemId(int arg0) {

    return arg0;
}


public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);
    iv.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200,120));
    iv.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
    return iv;
}
```

}
}

this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wallpaper.rahuldravid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />

</manifest>
```

This is the logcat :

```
05-22 19:30:21.008: D/AndroidRuntime(30838): Shutting down VM
05-22 19:30:21.008: W/dalvikvm(30838): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a9f210)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.wallpaper.rahuldravid/com.wallpaper.rahuldravid.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at com.wallpaper.rahuldravid.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:28)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
05-22 19:30:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(30838):    ... 11 more
```

I have searched all over and the solution i found mostly was to make sure the activity name is right in the code and the manifest.As you can see its correct. Can you please help me out with this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here:

```
ImageView imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);;
```

you are trying to initialize `imageView` instance before setting Layout for current Activity. so move all View initialization inside `onCreate` method of Activity after `setContentView` as:

```
// declare all Views here...
ImageView imageView;  //<<<
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // initialize Views here after setting layout for Activity..
    imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);  //<<<<

    Gallery ga = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't do `ImageView imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);` before setting content view in your onCreate